# Which is correct? "I eager to..." or "I am eager for..."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Assume I like to meet my friend and I want to say my feelings to him.

Which should I use ?

```
1) I eager to you.

2) I am eager for you.

3) I eager for you.

4) I eager you.
```

or something else...?

Comment: Even on ELL you're expected to show evidence of *some* "prior research". Which I suspect would have led to to realise that ***eager*** is ***not a verb*** (it was an *extremely* rare verb until about 500 years ago, but you probably wouldn't find that anywhere except in the full OED).

Answer (score 4):

I'd say

> I am eager to speak to you.

(if the feelings saying is more important) or

> I am eager to meet you.

if not.

1), 3) and 4) are not correct because 'eager' is not a verb.

2) sounds strange because 'to be eager for' + a person means that you want someone to do or experience *something*, like in 'I am eager for you to meet my family'.

Comment: Question edited. What about number 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

In all but one of your examples you are lacking a verb. In example 2 you are implying that you are eager for them to do something, but you don't specify what that is.

> I eager to you.

I ***am*** eager to ***meet*** you.

> I am eager for you.

I am eager for you ***to do something***.

> I eager for you.

I ***am*** eager for you ***to do something***.

> I eager you.

I ***am*** eager ***to meet*** you.

The second example is most correct because you use the verb "am", which is a derivative of "to be". In this context, am is helping you express a state of emotion or being.

When you use the word eager, you are expressing how you feel about a certain situation or event. You want to make sure that you say what that situation or event is. What you really want to answer is "What am I eager for?". In this case your answer would be "I am eager to meet you."

Comment: *I am eager for you.* might get quite personal. In a relationship, it is more like "I am eager to do something with you.", and I don't mean going shopping.

Comment: I was quoting OP, though I agree. Gave me a chuckle.